# I want to install ssh in ubuntu19,but it occurs some error,sshd_config can not found,how can I solve those problems,thanks

Tags: ssh, openssh, ubuntu-19.04

[image]

service ssh start does not work,
and when I want to install openssh-server,it also occurs some problems
[image]

Comment: try `sudo service ssh enable`, then `sudo service ssh restart`

Comment: when I enter the service ssh restart,it response that "Failed to restart ssh.service: Unit ssh.service is masked."

Comment: `sudo systemctl unmask ssh`, then try to enable + restart service again